# Can theta be interchanged with x?

Tags: calculus, integration

Can the following integral have theta replaced with x?
$$\int_0^\pi\ (\sqrt{ 1+\cos2\theta})^3  d\theta$$

The new integral would look like this
$$\int_0^\pi\ (\sqrt{ 1+\cos2x})^3  dx$$

Does the theta symbol mean anything other than just a variable?

Comment: It is the same.  It is just traditional to use $\theta$ when you are thinking of the variable as an angle.

Comment: This is an example of a "dummy variable". It's just like the variable used as the index in a summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a variable as long as you change it everywhere (as you did).